# How to get Json data from a remote app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a controller in my rails app that renderes json data

```
def show
 @visit = Visit.all
 @count = @visit.first.count unless @visit == [] 
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @visit.first }
  format.json {render :partial => "this.json"}
 end
end
```

i my other app i do a simple ajax request to get the json string from my view

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://url.com/show.json', 
success: function( data ){
    console.log(data);
  $('#data').html(data);
 }
});​
```

for the crossdomain headers i use Rack Cors

```
use Rack::Cors do
 allow do
  origins '*'
  # regular expressions can be used here
  resource '/countvisit/*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
  # headers to expose
 end
end
```

I am not gwetting anything back from the ajax request. Any idea of why this might happen??

Comment: is your partial file named correctly? _this.json.erb ?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to render 'this.json' partial and not the actual json string.

Shouldn't it be `format.json {render :json=> "this.json"}` instead?

Comment: now i get this
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url.com/show.json. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

AM i doing somthing wrong with the crossdomain file

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies i fixed it by adding a callback at the end of the url and getting a jsonP instead so now i am able to get the value.

Comment: Hello all again, i managed to solve the issue by using jsonp but it is working only in jsfiddle. In my host i still get the crossdomain error. Any idea why this can happen?

Comment: ¿What do you see when you access /show.json with your browser? As pointed out @ismaelga your partial hds to be named `_this.json` on the first code you post. Will update my curren answer after getting more info